# botão back menu ionic v3

Tags: javascript, html, ionic

Bom dia a todos.

Tenho uma dúvida, quando clico no menu e escolho uma das opções, ele carrega uma nova page, mas me parece que na pilha fica a pagina anterior que contem o acesso ao menu ao qual cliquei..

Ex:
Page Home - contem o menu, clico sobre ele e tenho opções como: Page 1, Page 2 ...

Eu estou testando pelo navegador.. Ao clicar na opção Page 1 do menu, ao invés de carregar na pilha a Page 1, não carrega. Fica a Home..

http://localhost:8100/home -> não deveria mudar para http://localhost:8100/page1 ?

Eu entendo como funciona a pilha conforme navego por pagina, mas quando navego pelo menu parece que muda... ou estou completamente enganado ou desconheço mesmo..

Portanto, não aparece o botão back na Page 1.. para eu voltar a page Home..

e preciso deste backbutton, como resolvo isso????? Me ajudem por favor.

e obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Na função do menu que abre uma nova página, verifique o seguinte:

Se a função chamar uma nova página assim (abaixo), vc vai resetar a pilha e colocar a página que vc clicou como PageRoot (primeira) da pilha. Nesse caso vc não consegue voltar para a HomePage pois a primeira página da pilha será a Page1

```
this.nav.setRoot('Page1');
```

Caso esteja assim (abaixo), vc estará empilhando mais uma página na pilha que já existe. Se vc está na HomePage, abre o menu e clica na Page1, ai sim vc conseguirá retornar a HomePage com o backButton.

```
this.nav.push('Page1');
```

O problema desse segundo exemplo, é que em qualquer página que vc esteja, por exemplo, vc navegou pela HomePage > Page1 > Page2. Na Page2 vc abre o menu e clica na Page1. Vc estará empilhando novamente a Page1 na pilha.
Ex. HomePage > Page1 > Page2 > Page1.

----- Edit: -----

Na documentação do NavController achei isso:

```
openPage(page: string) {
    this.nav.setPages(['HomePage', page]);
}
```

Você pode setar sempre a HomePage como a primeira da pilha. Então o backButton irá sempre aparecer e voltar para a HomePage.

Comment: A última deu certinho Gesiel Rosa.. Você foi imprescindível para esta resolução meu caro amigo. Obrigado mesmo! Salvou a semana... mania de não ler a documentação!!!! Preciso aprender a ler a documentação.. O desespero e a falta de paciencia nos faz perder tempo, ainda bem que temos esta comunidade e podemos encontrar pessoas qualificadas. Forte abraço e obrigado novamente.

Comment: Documentação do Ionic é muito completa. Abraços